# How to handle multiple questions within one utterance?

Tags: chat, chatbot, aiml, pandorabots

Sample:

```
User: How old are you and where do you live ?
Alice: I'm 7 months old. I live on earth.
```

My try:

```
<category>
    <pattern>WHERE DO YOU LIVE</pattern>
    <template>I live on earth.</template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>HOW OLD ARE YOU</pattern>
    <template>I'm 7 months old.</template>
</category>
```

The above AIML code can only reply if I ask the two questions separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By digging into [AIML syntax](http://www.aiml.foundation/doc.html), I finally found a solution with the `<srai>` tag:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE inline_dtd[
<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
]>
<aiml version="2.0">
    <category>
        <pattern>WHERE DO YOU LIVE</pattern>
        <template>I live on earth.</template>
    </category>

    <category>
        <pattern>HOW OLD ARE YOU</pattern>
        <template>I'm 7 months old.</template>
    </category>

    <category>
        <pattern>HOW OLD ARE YOU AND WHERE DO YOU LIVE</pattern>
        <template>
            <srai>HOW OLD ARE YOU</srai>
            &nbsp;
            <srai>WHERE DO YOU LIVE</srai>
        </template>
    </category>
</aiml>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use wildcards to improve this. Now we can answer things like, "How are you and where is London"

```
<category>
    <pattern>HOW _ AND WHERE *</pattern>
    <template>
        <srai>HOW <star/></srai>
        <srai>WHERE <star index="2"/></srai>
    </template>
</category>
```